# Swap order of list of lists IF element in 1 list is higher than the element of a second list

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting

I have a list of lists and I am creating a copy of it in order to perform some sorting on it based on the value in the last index of each list.

The good news is that I have this part sorted.

The bad news is that I cannot figure out how to perform a secondary sort if there are two inner lists that have the same value in the last index of each list.

I have tried doing a similar for loop inside the original for loop but that just re-sorted the list based on the element in index 0 and ignores the original sort.

I hope this makes sense.

Here is the code so far which is successfully doing the descending sort based on the elements in index -1
I want to learn how to do this using just loops or creating temp variables for swaps.
I want to avoid using methods such as pop and can't use libraries such as pandas

Thanks in advance to anyone who takes the time to read and reply :)

EDIT: added character list, actual output and wanted output below

```
character_list = [['Prince', 10000, 5], ['Madonna', 500000, 5], ['The Wiggles', 50, 4], ['Elton John', 50000, 3], ['Dr Dre', 100000, 3], ['Justin Bieber', 35000, 4]]

# Defining the function to display highest battles won
def sort_by_health():
    
    unsorted_character_list_copy = character_list.copy()
    sorted_character_list = []
    
    for i in range(len(unsorted_character_list_copy)):
        max_value = unsorted_character_list_copy[-1]
        for x in unsorted_character_list_copy:
            if x[-1] > max_value[-1]:
                max_value = x
        sorted_character_list.append(max_value)
        unsorted_character_list_copy.remove(max_value)


for character in sorted_character_list():
    print(character)

#Output

['Prince', 10000, 5]
['Madonna', 500000, 5]
['Justin Bieber', 35000, 4]
['The Wiggles', 50, 4]
['Dr Dre', 100000, 3]
['Elton John', 50000, 3]

# Desired Output is to first sort by index -1 which is what it is doing
# But if there are more than 1 sublist with the same value at index -1 
# Then do a secondary descending sort on index 1

['Madonna', 500000, 5]
['Prince', 10000, 5]
['Justin Bieber', 35000, 4]
['The Wiggles', 50, 4]
['Dr Dre', 100000, 3]
['Elton John', 50000, 3]
```

Comment: Could you give two inputs and two expected outputs for the two scenarios you mentioned?

Comment: You could use the built-in function [sorted](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) with the `key` being the sublist reversed - `sorted(character_list, key=lambda l: l[::-1], reverse=True)`

Comment: @EduardoGomes edited original post with inputs and outputs, including actual and desired output. Thnx.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. It is probably not the most pythonic way to do it but here is what I ended up coding that worked. Finally.

```
new_character_list = [['Prince', 100, 5], ['Madonna', 500000, 5], ['The Wiggles', 50, 4], ['Elton John', 1000000, 3], ['Dr Dre', 1000000000, 3], ['Justin Bieber', 35000, 4]]

def sort_by_health():
    
    unsorted_character_list_copy = new_character_list.copy()
    sorted_character_list = []

    for i in range(len(unsorted_character_list_copy)):
        max_value = unsorted_character_list_copy[-1]
        for x in unsorted_character_list_copy:
            if x[-1] > max_value[-1]:
                max_value = x
        sorted_character_list.append(max_value)
        unsorted_character_list_copy.remove(max_value)
    
    count = 0
    items_in_list = int(len(sorted_character_list)) 
    
    for i in range(items_in_list - 1):
        print(count)
        if sorted_character_list[count][1] < sorted_character_list[count+1][1] and sorted_character_list[count][-1] == sorted_character_list[count+1][-1]:
            sorted_character_list[count], sorted_character_list[count+1] = sorted_character_list[count+1], sorted_character_list[count]
        count += 1
        print(count)
        
    for i in sorted_character_list:
        print(i)
        
sort_by_health()
```